# AWS EBS volume snapshot is missing files

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot

I have a script that creates some files on a certain volume for an EC2 instance. This volume is then snapshotted. The snapshot is used to create a new volume in turn, and this new volume is then attached to another EC2 instance. I can see the files are definitely there on the source system. But they are missing from the target. Sometimes completely missing, sometimes they are there with zero size - I ran a few test iterations. They are a few kb in size but important configuration files. My script even runs sync command on the file system to make sure the cached files are written to disk before snapshot. Can anybody think anything else I may have missed. Looks like if the files are already created for a longer time and then I create a snapshot then files are there too on the snapshot. So it still looks like some caching / EBS write delay by the time I am taking the snapshots but not sure what else can I do besides sync command.

Comment: the creation of files and snapshot afterwards is all done by your script? If yes, then maybe share the code. Maybe you trigegr the snapshot before the data has been written to the source. In worst case scenario, which you shouldn't do by the way, put a sleep between writing of files and creation of the snapshot

Comment: Snapshots are simply copies of the underlying disk blocks. The Snapshot system has no concept of files or what is stored on the disk. It sounds like data not being flushed to disk, but you say that you cater for that with `sync`. Any chance you can trigger a reboot before the Snapshot, to make sure everything is saved?

Comment: looks like the issue was that I synced the file system with root. once I did the device as well, it was OK. I also synced the file system with the user I was using it.